# Affix that makes nouns into verbs and verbs into nouns?

Tags: terminology, cross-linguistic, verbs, nouns, morphological-typology

I have a friend studying a language from the pacific islands, and she found an affix that when added to a noun makes a verb and when added to a verb makes a noun. What would you call such a thing, and how might one find it in the literature?

Comment: A nominalizer (noun-forming); a verbalizing affix (verb-forming).

Comment: It's not always clear what's a noun and what's a verb in Austronesian languages. And a great deal depends on the constructions involved.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this a single affix that provides both functions? Do you know if it can be applied multiple times?

Comment: It provides both functions, but in one case an additional morpheme is added.

Comment: I'm interested to know which Pacific Island language that is. :)

Comment: @sventech: Well that makes it sound like two related affixes to me, and not one affix like you state. Like `-foo` turninging verbs into nouns and `-foobar` turning nouns into verbs?

Comment: @hippietrail  Yes, the situation is quite complicated and my friend is more familiar with it than I am. In this case -bar has more than a half dozen forms. I believe there are different specific kinds of verbs and nouns that can be formed.

Comment: In that case I believe this question is quite meaningless as an abstract question and it would've been a better idea to ask a question about the actual language and affixes involved.

Comment: The question was one of terminology. I think I explained the situation well, but people wanted to second-guess the analysis of the morphology.

Comment: @Noble_Bright_Life Now that some time has passed, I'll say that the language in question is Natügu / Natqgu of the Santa Cruz Islands.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

I would suggest calling this/these affix(es) either a **nominalising affix** or a **verbalising affix**, depending on its context. (See Additional Information below.)

## Reasoning

These terms are already present in literature as seen below:

1. [Morphological Productivity (Cambridge; Google Books)](http://books.google.com/books?id=xt15qmqx7UcC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=morphological%20terms%20nominalisation&source=bl&ots=WT14E55fGd&sig=bTHRkGdtXtmP9HjqF1RvTZey8NI&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=sg0EUcWXKqvH0AHcjYCYBQ&ved=0CGYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=morphological%20terms%20nominalisation&f=false) gives
   examples of nominalisation affixes in English:

   > *-ment*, *-tion*, *-ity*

   ... and examples of "verbifying/verbalising" affixes:

   > *-ate*, *-ise*
2. [Wikipedia: Nominalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization)

   (see link for contents; gives lots of linguistic examples)

## Additional Information

Languages do map different morphological processes to sometimes the same phone. For example in English, we have *-s*, which is called either a *plural(-ising) affix* or a *possessive affix*, depending on its context, because it will either turn a singular word plural or it will signify possession of a noun. Therefore, approaching this problem as a native-English speaker, I stick true to the aforementioned suggestions.

*However*, [jlawler](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/482/jlawler) mentions above:

> It's not always clear what's a noun and what's a verb in Austronesian languages.

With this new information in mind, perhaps a native speaker of an Austronesian language does not necessarily differentiate nouns/verbs as I do. This difference might then promote your friend to call this paradigm something specific to Austronesian languages. If such a term *does not exist* in specific literature, then typically your friend can simply coin an appropriate term.

Comment: Perhaps a grammaticalizer (since class change is sometimes called grammaticalization). The idea is a single word for it, since it is the same morpheme and cannot co-occur with itself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers and comments! My friend is going with the term derivational affix (abbreviation DER) as used by Karen Ashley (who works on the Sa'a language of the Solomon Islands). Seems a bit vague, but I guess it was necessary to show it is the same morpheme performing both functions. I'll try to release more info when the paper is published. :-)

Comment: well the same phenomenon could be seen in Turkic languages when same suffix is used to make Noun from verb and verb from noun. And it can be applied just ones.

Comment: Well *derivation affix* is more general and covers many kinds of affix unlike your specific two given properties of `n->v` and `v->n`. It's even less specific than Sean's answers. Maybe *nominalising and verbalising affix*?

Comment: @Dariya Do you happen to know what term is used for that suffix in the analysis of Turkic languages?

Comment: generally they are analysed as two different derivational homophonic suffixes. one as nominalising and other as verbalising as others have already said.

Comment: @Dariya That is unfortunate. It sounds to me like linguists are afraid to rock the boat. It appears to be happening cross-linguistically that the same morpheme can perform "opposite" functions, but English and other European languages have prejudiced us against the possibility.

Comment: @sventech I totally agree with you. Most of the linguistic hypothethis based on European languages. You may be the first who will bring up this "opposite" function morphemes' issue. So go ahead! If you need Kyrgyz data at any point, I would be happy to help you.

Comment: @Dariya -- I spoke with my friend who is at a conference in Australia and she'd really like to see the data from Kyrgyz or other Turkic languages. Can you send something to my email address (visible on my profile)?